# Old code : access arguments of a function passed as an argument to another function?

Tags: c++, ellipsis

I have to maintain an old piece of code which does not work correctly anymore when compiled on 64k machines.

I have a function "solve" calling another function "funct" passed as a pointer:

`int solve(double*x,double xA,double xB,double zeps,double funct(double x,double*),...)`

Therefore, "solve" can be used with different possible functions as for example :

`double isDgood(double D,double*Y);`

From within the function "solve", it was possible to call the function "funct" and access its arguments using:

`fA=funct(xA,(double*)(&funct+1));"`

Although I am not familiar with this syntax, I guess that the developer was assuming that the unspecified arguments were just pushed in the stack. However, this code does not work anymore on 64k platforms. How can I correct this code? Should I specifically use Va_list?

Thanks you very much for your help.

Comment: Yes, you would need to use the VA mechanics for that. As it is, it's invoking _Undefined Behavior_. (Which for years did what was the intention of the code.) However, wouldn't this be a great opportunity to modernize the code? Use function objects instead - the caller provides the arguments to the function object's constructor, and your `solve` function only calls it. You can even create these on the fly using `std/boost::bind()`.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I will try to use va_list.Thanks again !

Answer (score 2):

That's horrifically undefined behaviour. If you want to access the argument, you will have to pass them around.